# Getting the value of an item from a SelectListItem List?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following class:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDatastore()
{
    return new[]
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = "DEV", Text = "Development"  },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "DC1", Text = "Production" },
        };
}
```

What I need is to execute a function to return the Datastore name. Something like

```
var abc = getDatastoreName("DEV").
```

Do I need to do this with LINQ or is there some easy way? How could I code this function?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string getDatastoreName(string name)
{
     var result = GetDatastore().SingleOrDefault(s => s.Value == name);
     if (result != null)
     {
         return result.Text;
     }
     throw /* some exception */
}
```

The `Value` property of `SelectListItem` is usually unique and hence I have `SingleOrDefault()`. If that is not the case then you can switch to using `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple LINQ query can find the value you want:

```
var val = dataStore.Where(d => d.Value == "DEV").FirstOrDefault();
//`val` will be the item, or null if the item doesn't exist in the list
```

But this is only good for small lists of items -- it's worst-case Order N.

If you wanted a better search, you could store your data as a dictionary with the keys being used as item values, for example, and databind against that rather than against a list of `SelectListItems`. That would allow you to look up the values constant time.

For most cases, simple LINQ will be fine. If you have a big list, or you're querying that list frequently... consider an alternative.

Comment: Thanks very much. I will mark as accepted. My list is small and just at the most five items but what do you mean "worst-case Order N"

Comment: @M Jacob: I highly suggest you read up on [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for more information, but "Order N" basically means that when you execute the query, it will undergo `C * N` operations, where C is an unknown and typically irrelevant constant value and N is the number of items in your list.

Comment: My suggestion to use a dictionary is a better choice for performance because the operation would be `O(1)` (Order 1, or constant time). It's actually a worse choice for small lists, since calculating a hash, while constant and predictable, is typically slower than a couple dozen (or so) iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are searching something like this
i have "Details" page that works perfectly:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Code1dItems.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Value == model.Code1Id.ToString()).Text, new { @class = "Width100P" })
```

In my model :

Code1Id is int value and it comes from database Code1dItems is IEnumerable
value like 'GetDatastore' and returns ID->string, ID value matches with Code1d and Text->string

depending on your question you should use :

```
string abc = GetDatastore.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Value == "DEV").Text
```

if you get value from database you should use my code example.